# JS/jQuery Check if on root web of root sitecollection

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, site-collection

How is it possible to check in JS/jQuery if the user is on the root site of the root sitecollection in the webapplication? (Sharepoint 2010)

Thanks!

**Example:**

- http://www.mysite.com/Pages/Whatever.aspx     -> ROOT WEB & ROOT SITECOLLECTION
- http://www.mysite.com/subsite/Pages/Test.aspx -> **NOT** ROOT WEB & ROOT SITECOLLECTION
- http://www.mysite.com/sites/Random/Pages/Awesome.aspx -> ROOT WEB & **NOT** ROOT SITECOLLECTION
- http://www.mysite.com/sites/Random/subsite/Pages/Awesome.aspx -> **NOT** ROOT WEB & **NOT** ROOT SITECOLLECTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by adding a usercontrol to the masterpage where I check the current url. If it passes as rootweb from sitecollection, then I use the scriptmanager to write a clientscriptblock into the page. I guess using a webservice was also a possibility, but the fastest way for me was this one...

Answer (score 5):

I like @Vardhaman Deshpande's answer. But as I understand the question, we must check if it is on the rootweb (root site) in a site collection. A site collection can have different url than "/". But using _spPageContextInfo is absolutely right. So in javascript, to determine if it is a root web or not:

```
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
var isRootWeb = siteUrl == webUrl;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ECMAScript to achieve it.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var rootWeb = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb(); //always return the root web of the site collection
```

See some examples [here](http://antoniolanaro.blogspot.se/2011/05/ecmascript-how-to-get-lists.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I need the root web of the ROOT SITECOLLECTION

Comment: The scope of client object model is site collection, you cannot access to the content out of the current site collection. You'll need to manually use the web services on the client side, perhaps using SPServices, to interact with the root site collection.

Comment: **An alternative solution** to your problem could be to put a property bag in the root web of your root site collection and try to find it using ECMAScript. If you find the property bag then you are on root web of root site collection else it's other site collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the _spPageContextInfo global object in SharePoint JavaScript:
http://blog.tedpattison.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=9

The `_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl` value will always be `"/"` if you are on the root site.

Answer (score 0):

If you *had* to do it client side, you could check the `L_Menu_BaseUrl` variable. If it's blank you're on a root site.